# What is the substantial difference between transit orbits and manifold trajectories in the frame of circular restricted three body problem?

Tags: lagrangian-points, three-body, low-energy-transfer

In my MSc thesis I faced the problem of unstable hyperbolic invariant manifold trajectories (UHIMs) emanating from planar Lyapunov orbits around two collinear Lagrange points L1 and L2 of the Sun-Earth/Moon Circular Restricted 3 Body Problem (CR3BP). My tutor told me that transit orbits also exist and he told me to search on the web for further information about them. Can you provide me a simple explanation about the difference between these transit orbits and the UHIMs?